# Using module in lib folder in tests

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I have this module in my lib folder:

```
module Exceptions
   class NotAuthorized < StandardError
   end
end
```

Then, I have a test for a controller like this:

```
class Admin::ApplicationControllerTest < ActionController::TestCase

   test "should not be authorized" do
      assert_raise(Exceptions::NotAuthorized) {
        get :index
      }
   end
end
```

I also try to put this line on my environments/test.rb

```
config.autoload_paths +=%W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

But, when I run the test I always get:

```
NameError: unitialized constant Admin::ApplicationControllerTest::Exceptions
```

How to include the module Exceptions in the test?

Answer (score 0):

Moving

```
config.autoload_paths +=%W(#{config.root}/lib)
```

to application.rb fix it.